# How can I make div elements in one line

Tags: html, css, display

I am trying to create a ticket-buying page where a user inputs some answers and at the end their information should display as following:

From: New York

To: Chicago

When: 26th of May

and so on.

I just cant get my elements to be displayed like that.

Here is the code:

```
<h2>Booking a ticket</h2>
<div id="bookingBefore">
  <h4>Please enter your name</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Just like your ID" id="name">
  <h4>Please enter your surname</h4>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Just like your ID" id="surname">
  <h4>Please enter your date of birth</h4>
  <input type="date" placeholder="Just like your ID" id="dateOfBirth">
  <h4>Date of Birth</h4> <h3></h3>
  <h4>Type of ID</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="IDtype" value="Passport" id="passport">
  <label for="passport">Passport</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="IDtype" value="ID-card" id="ID-card">
  <label for="ID-card">ID-Card</label>

  <h4 id="from">From where?</h4>
  <select name="Cities" id="citiesFrom">
    <option value="Tashkent">Tashkent</option>
    <option value="Andijan">Andijan</option>
    <option value="Namangan">Namangan</option>
    <option value="Fergana">Fergana</option>
  </select>
  <h4 id="to">To where?</h4>
  <select name="Cities" id="citiesTo">
    <option value="Tashkent">Tashkent</option>
    <option value="Andijan">Andijan</option>
    <option value="Namangan">Namangan</option>
    <option value="Fergana">Fergana</option>
  </select>

  <h2>When do you want to leave?</h2>
  <input type="date" id="flightDate">
  <h3>How would you like to pay?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Passport" id="byCard">
  <label for="passport">By Card</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="ID-card" id="inCash">
  <label for="ID-card">In Cash</label>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="bookingAfter">
  <div id="formBefore">
    <h4>Surname:</h4>
  <h4>Name:</h4>
  <h4>Type of ID</h4>
  <h4>From</h4>
  <h4>To</h4>
  <h4>Flight date</h4>
  <h4>Type of Payment</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="formAfter">
    <h3 id="surnameafter"></h3>
  <h3 id="nameafter"></h3>
  <h3 id="IDafter"></h3>
  <h3 id="fromafter"></h3>
  <h3 id="toafter"></h3>
  <h3 id="flightdateAfter"></h3>
  <h3 id="paymentAfter"></h3>
  </div>

  <button id="confirm">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Please add your css here

Comment: Place your input inside your h4.

Comment: Well, I don't really have the CSS file. I tried to use inline, float, and others but didn't work so I deleted it.

Comment: I can't make it work is not a clear question. What exactly is the problem. Are you getting errors somewhere? Is there an output somewhere?

Comment: Ok. So first, you input some stuff like your name and destination and stuff. After you submit them, there should be a table like text you know, like this:  Name: Black  Destination: New York and so on. When I input my names and other details and submit them, it showing like a block of elements. (i.e. Surname and under it, the surname you inputted. But they shouldn't be under one another. They should be beside one another). I hope I could explain it

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div style="display: flex">
     <h5>From: &nbsp;</h5>
     <h5>New York</h5>
</div>
<div style="display: flex">
     <h5>To: &nbsp;</h5>
     <h5>Chicago</h5>
</div>
<div style="display: flex">
     <h5>When: &nbsp;</h5>
     <h5>26th of May</h5>
</div>
```